# How to retrieve an array in Simple MVC Framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

How can I retrieve an array in Simple MVC Framework to show error messages if some input fields are not valid?

Controller:

```
public function index($error)
{
    $data ['title'] = $this->language->get('welcome_text');

    View::renderTemplate('header', $data);
    View::render('insert/form', $data);
    View::renderTemplate('footer', $data);
}

public function save()
{
    if (isset($_POST)) {

        $data ['is_valid'] = \Helpers\Gump::is_valid($_POST, array(
            'firstname' => 'required|min_len,2'
        ));

        if ($data ['is_valid'] === true) {
            // continue
        } else {
            $this->index($data ['is_valid']); // show error messages
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"><?php var_dump($error); ?></div>
... <button type="submit">Save (calls save())</button>
```

var_dump($error) always shows bool(false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you wasn't sent error to render, as i see.

```
public function index($error)
{
    $data ['title'] = $this->language->get('welcome_text');
    $data ['error'] = $error;

    View::renderTemplate('header', $data);
    View::render('insert/form', $data);
    View::renderTemplate('footer', $data);
}
```

View

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"><?php var_dump($data['error']); ?></div>
```